# Can C# custom attributes get the parameters of the method they are attached to?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I have a custom attribute and would like to be able to inspect the signature of the item it is attached to from inside the attribute's code.

This would be easy from outside the attribute, but it specifically needs to be inside the attribute.  I've tried traversing StackTrace but this does not get the method I'm attaching to, and CallerMemberName also does not get me what I need.

```cs
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
  public void ReadDetails()
  {
    MethodInfo attachee = ???; // TODO

    Console.WriteLine(attachee.MethodName); // expect "Baa"
    Console.WriteLine(attachee.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name); // expect "int"
    Console.WriteLine(attachee.GetParameters()[0].Name); // expect "a"
  }
}

public class foo
{
  [MyAttribute]
  public void Baa(int a, string b) {}
}
```

For context, this is to support some automated testing - I have a spreadsheet of data describing a user interface, and test methods with fewer parameters than the spreadsheet has columns.  I have a custom attribute which subclasses NUnit TestCaseSourceAttribute and reads the spreadsheet, but needs to filter the columns down to just what the test case needs.  For example I'll have tests like:

```cs
[SpreadsheetDrivenTests("ui.xlsx")]
public void TestButtonText(string buttonId, string expectedText) {}

[SpreadsheetDrivenTests("ui.xlsx")]
public void TestButtonVisibility(string buttonId, bool expectedVisible) {}
```

Note that part of the motivation for this is to avoid specifying parameters twice per method.  The below solutions would be sub-optimal (but easily done)

```cs
[SpreadsheetDrivenTests("ui.xlsx", "buttonId", "expectedText")]
public void TestButtonText(string buttonId, string expectedText) {}

[SpreadsheetDrivenTests("ui.xlsx", typeof(this), nameof(ParameterGenerator)]
public void TestButtonVisibility(string buttonId, bool expectedVisible) {}

public static string[] ParameterGenerator()
{
  return { "buttonId", "expectedVisible" };
}
```

Comment: Could you instead pass this information into an instance method in `MyAttribute` from wherever you get the attribute instance?

Comment: John, I'm trying to avoid passing extra arguments.  I could do something like [SpreadsheetDrivenTests("ui.xlsx", "buttonId", "expectedText")]  or [SpreadsheetDrivenTests("ui.xlsx", typeof(this), nameof(MethodThatGetsMyParameters)] but I'd effectively be specifying my parameters twice for each method.  Unless I've misunderstood your suggestion?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. To use an attribute, you need to do something like `.GetCustomAttribute<SpeadsheetDrivenTests>()`, right? Well, at that point you have all of that other information, right? So my question is, is there a reason why you can't pass the extra information at this point?

Comment: Ah, I see.  You're right, but I don't have control of that code - it's baked into NUnit somewhere.